# How would I find the farthest matching file

Tags: javascript, node.js

The title makes no sense to a closest-to-the-box person, but it will make sense.

I'm trying to make a custom-code HTTP server. the code works completely, but I want to add a 404 page.
when you get the 404 page, I want to show more than text.

this is what I have without that addition:

```
http = require("http");
fs = require("fs");

server = {};

server.http = http.createServer((request, response)=>{
  request.path = request.url.split("?")[0];
  if(request.url.split("?").length>1){
    request.query = request.url.split("?")[1];
    request.query = request.query.split('&');
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < request.query.length; i++) {
      var cur = request.query[i].split('=');
      result[decodeURIComponent(cur[0])] = decodeURIComponent(cur[1]);
    }
    request.query = result;
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log(request.headers, request.path, request.query);
  fs.readFile(`Public/HTTP/Scripts${request.path}.js`, "utf-8", (directError, script)=>{
    if(directError){
      if(directError.message == `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Public/HTTP/Sripts${request.path}.js'`){
        //this is where I would like that code. i was thinking a for loop would work but then i got really confused, so, here i am.
      }
    } else {
      fs.readFile(`Public/HTTP/Send${request.path}.file`, (A, sendFile)=>{
        eval(script);
      });
    }
  })
});

server.http.listen();
console.clear();
```

The question without the extras is:
How do I go through file folders backward until I find a folder with the file I need?
I don't even know what I mean, but even more broken down in an example:

`/a/path/to/a/file_that/doesn't_exist` is request.url.

`a`, `to`, and `file_that` all have the file with the 404 response code.

I want it to get `file_that`s 404 script because it is the last.

I am so sorry if you still don't understand me. I'm new here and Idk how else to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Express NodeJS Library is the industry standard framework for defining routes.
Express automatically finds the farthest file and sends an error.

If you use express, you can write

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send("public/error-404.html") //Where error-404.html is your custom HTML Page
    return;
});
```

You can follow the [official guide](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) to implement Express in your app

Comment: I'm so sorry, but i decided Stack Overflow isn't my place. also THIS IS PERSONAL CODE so idc if stack overflow bans me or something. i am not an industry nor work in, one that needs me for my programming skills. i would be better off working at chick fil a anyway. again, sorry, but no.